# What is the purpose of Vs and Vb pins in IR2110

Tags: integrated-circuit, mosfet-driver, bridge

I can't understand the purpose of these 2 pins and why the output wire from both the source of the high MOSFET and the drain of the low MOSFET is connected  with pin Vs in the half-bridge circuit.[image: IR2110 application diagram]

Answer (score 2):

Vs and Vb are the boostrap capacitor connections, and Vs is the source connection for the high-side gate driver.

When the load voltage is low, the boostrap capacitor charges from Vcc through the diode (and the low side MOSFET). When the load voltage is high the bootstrap capacitor (briefly) provides power supply voltage for the high side gate driver.

This is a way of providing gate drive for an N-channel MOSFET on the high side, so it is Vcc-Vf(diode) higher than the "up to 500V" supply.

The circuit is expected to switch continuously. It cannot hold the output high indefinitely.

The connections marked "TO LOAD" should be connected together.

Answer (score 2):

> *I can't understand the purpose of these 2 pins and why the output wire
> from both the source of the high MOSFET and the drain of low MOSFET is
> connected with pin Vs in half bridge circuit.*

- To properly turn on the upper MOSFET you need to raise its gate voltage maybe 10 volts higher than the voltage on the source.
- And, if you want to have that upper MOSFET act as a decent low-ohm switch, you would expect the source voltage to be close to 500 volts (the drain voltage)
- This inevitably means that the gate voltage needs to rise to around 510 volts when properly turning on the upper MOSFET
- Of course, if the upper MOSFET drain voltage is only 150 volts then the gate needs to rise to about 160 volts.

Welcome to the bootstrap circuit. The bootstrap capacitor connected between VB and VS gets charged up to Vcc minus one diode drop and, when the upper MOSFET is needed to be activated, the rising voltage on the common source/drain pin raises VB several volts higher than the source and, this is used to power the internal upper MOSFET driver.

To make a half bridge driver, you must have the source of the upper MOSFET connected to the drain of the lower MOSFET. Without that connection it isn't a half-bridge circuit: -

[image]

Image from [here, Infineon half bridge drivers](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/gate-driver-ics/half-bridge-drivers/).

[Here's a suitable explanation of bootstrapping in more detail](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/624470/how-is-a-highside-gate-powered-with-a-bootstrap-circuit-and-mosfet-driver)

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I understood what you said , but why is the output wire i.e the wire that connects the source of the high side with drain of the low is then connected with vs , why we just make only the bootstrap capacitor connected with Vs pin

Comment: The internal driver in the chip needs a connection to Vs so that it can produce a 10 volt (ish) higher voltage to drive the upper MOSFET gate. And the capacitor is fundamental to  storing the energy to do that. Try reading the bottom link in my answer.

Comment: OK thanks so much , I will read it .

Answer (score 1):

From [International Rectifier Application Note AN-978 - HV Floating MOS-Gate Driver ICs](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2254418.pdf)

> 1. GATE DRIVE REQUIREMENTS OF HIGH-SIDE DEVICES
>    The gate drive requirements for a power MOSFET or IGBT utilized as a high-side switch (the drain is connected to the high voltage rail, as shown in Figure 1) driven in full enhancement (i.e., lowest voltage drop across its terminals) can be summarized as follows:

> 1. Gate voltage must be 10 V to 15 V higher than the source voltage. Being a high-side switch, such gate voltage would have to be higher than the rail voltage, which is frequently the highest voltage available in the system.

> 2. The gate voltage must be controllable from the logic, which is normally referenced to ground. Thus, the control signals have to be level-shifted to the source of the highside power device, which, in most applications, swings between the two rails.

[image]

The low side driver is Ground referenced so nothing needs to be done.  But the high side gate voltage has to be above the 500V drain voltage to work. The S pin is connected to the Source pin of the high side MOSFET.  To drive this MOSFET, the Gate pin must be 10-15V higher than the Source pin.  As in it must be level-shifted during MOSFET off time.