# Half-bridge driver giving high-side gate full input voltage

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, half-bridge

Using an [IRS2513](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRS2153D-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46269e1c019016a4ea5480f0d88) half bridge driver tuned at 30 kHz with [1MBH60-100](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/60635/FUJI/1MBH60-100.html) 1000 V, 60 A IGBTs, the driver is giving the high-side gate the full 24 V input voltage.

I have included a picture of how I configured the driver and how the oscilloscope looked when measuring (measured from HO to GND and LO to GND).

Why is this happening? The driver has an internal 15.4 V zener clamp.

[image: IRS2513]

[image: scope]

Comment: Do you measure the high-side gate drive output with respect to the ground or with respect to the high-side switch's source pin? Also, is there any load?

Comment: So are you asking about how a high-side bootstrap circuit works? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/624470/how-is-a-highside-gate-powered-with-a-bootstrap-circuit-and-mosfet-driver

Comment: @RohatKılıç I can't believe I missed that... Switching the HO probe's ground to VS, I am now measuring the correct voltage. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my scope probes were placed incorrectly. I was measuring from HO to Gnd and should have been measuring from HO to VS.

Comment: Make sure you didn't probe anything else whilst the gnd clip was connected to the `VS`.

Comment: Also don't forget to accept your own answer (as, apparently, your problem is solved) so that the question doesn't remain open.

Comment: Sure thing! However I cannot accept my own answer until two days have passed.